# make a string including \x in python

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I would like to make a string that includes "\x" but I get

```
invalid \x escape
```

error.

```
a = '\x'+''.join(lstDES[100][:2])+'\x'+''.join(lstDES[100][2:])
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: It turned out, based on the comments, that what OP actually wanted to do is not at all what is described here. The goal was actually to interpret the `lstDES[100][:2]` text as representing a character code in hexadecimal. It's not possible to just stick a backslash and a lowercase x in front of that text and get that effect; some explicit interpretation would be required.

Comment: I ended up changing the duplicate link to something completely different on that basis - it was hard to find the right one. This is why it's important to clarify questions and get a proper [mre] first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double the backslash to stop Python from interpreting it as a special character:

```
'\\x'
```

or use a raw string literal:

```
r'\x'
```

In regular Python string literals, backslashes signal the start of an escape sequence, and `\x` is a sequence that defines characters by their hexadecimal byte value.

You could use string formatting instead of all the concatenation here:

```
r'\x{0[0]}{0[1]}\x{0[2]}{0[3]}'.format(lstDES[100])
```

If you are trying to define two bytes based on the hex values from `lstDES[100]` then you'll have to use a different approach; producing a string with the characters `\`, `x` and two hex digits will not magically invoke the same interpretation Python uses for string literals.

You would use the [`binascii.unhexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) for that instead:

```
import binascii

a = binascii.unhexlify(''.join(lstDES[100][:4]))
```

Comment: the last command worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

In Python `\` is used to escape characters, such as `\n` for a newline or `\t` for a tab.

To have the literal string `'\x'` you need to use two backslashes, one to effectively escape the other,  so it becomes `'\\x'`.

```
In [199]: a = '\\x'

In [200]: print(a)
\x
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `\\x` because `\` used for escape the characters :

```
>>> s='\\x'+'a'
>>> print s
\xa
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a raw string as follows:

```
a = r'\x'+''.join(lstDES[100][:2]) + r'\x'+''.join(lstDES[100][2:])
```